# How to update model's attribute before saving model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In my project I need to update member's user attribute if it's empty.

I have this code in the model:

```php
class Member extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::saving(function ($model) {
            if (empty($model->user)) {
                $model->user = $model->email;
            }
        });
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'user',
        'password',
        // ...
    ];
    
    // ...
}
```

This is the migration for the model:

```php
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('user');
    $table->string('password');
    // ...
});
```

And I try to test it like this:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function shouldSetUserToEmailIfUserNotSet()
    {
        $instance = $this->model::factory([
            'user' => null
        ])->create();

        $model = $this->model::all()->first();

        $this->assertEquals($model->user, $model->email);
    }
```

So the user field is required in the database. And this is the test result:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 
NOT NULL constraint failed: members.user (SQL: insert into "members" ("password", "name", 
"email", "user", ...
```

And this error comes from the `->create();` line in the test.

So how should I set the `user` attribute on the model before save if it's not set?

Comment: Have you tried with the event `creating` instead of `saving` ?

Comment: I already tried it, same result.

Comment: I believe `public static function boot()` should be `protected static function boot()`

Comment: I changed, but not helped.

Comment: Just remembered; boot has changed is favor of `protected static function booted()` removing the need of `parent::boot();` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

Answer (score 1):

Use [Laravel's Mutator][1] for this:

```
public function setUserAttribute($value)
{
   if(empty($value){
     $this->attributes['user'] =  $this->attributes['email'];
   }
}


  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
static::saving(function (self $model) {
  if (empty($model->user)) {
   $model->forceFill(['user' => $model->email]);
   }
});
```

Comment: still the same error... I tried to put a `dd()` into `static::saving` function outside of the `if` statement, and the `dd` isn't run... Tried with `static::creating` too, same result. Is there any trick to make it work?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking try event fake

Comment: What if you `dd(empty($model->user))` and `$model->user` before the `if` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier the `dd` isn't run.

Comment: @RamilHuseynov `Event::fake()` will not help to me, because this is a lifecycle event, not a dispachable one - I think. And the other one: the create function gives the error, because the creating isn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `updating` instead of `creating`

```
 public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::updating(function ($model) {
            if (empty($model->user)) {
                $model->user = $model->email;
            }
        });
    }
```